# User Attendance Date Year and Month Wise

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a requirement to show user attendance year and month wise. Here is a sample
how it would look - Very basic:

```
Year - Jan - Feb
2018 - 26  - 20
2019 - 20  - 22
```

The data is retrieved from a single table and I tried the following query 
to do so:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE) "YEAR",
COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE)  = '1' THEN M.Id ELSE '-' END) "Jan",
COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE)  = '2' THEN M.Id ELSE '-' END) "Feb"
FROM TABLE m 
WHERE M.STATUS = 'P' AND M.Id = '12345678'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE) ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't return the expected data, instead it shows the yearly
attendance of a user for each month as follows:

```
Year - Jan - Feb
2018 - 292 - 292
2019 - 100 - 100
```

Did I miss something here? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE) "YEAR",
COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE)  = '1' THEN M.Id ELSE NULL END) "Jan",
COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE)  = '2' THEN M.Id ELSE NULL END) "Feb"
FROM TABLE m 
WHERE M.STATUS = 'P' AND M.Id = '12345678'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE) ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE);
```

OR-

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE) "YEAR",
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE)  = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Jan",
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE)  = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Feb"
FROM TABLE m 
WHERE M.STATUS = 'P' AND M.Id = '12345678'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE) ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `SUM()` for this.  But more importantly, your code is mixing types.  `EXTRACT()` returns a *number* so the comparison should be to a number.  I recommend:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE) as "YEAR",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Jan",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DATE) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Feb"
FROM TABLE m 
WHERE M.STATUS = 'P' AND
      M.Id = 12345678  -- I am guessing that `id` is also a number
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.DATE);
```

You should be careful mixing types.  Conversions can impede the ability of the optimizer to find the best query plan.